# Как создать объект внутри класса Java

Tags: java

Я уже задавал такой вопрос но решил немного переформулировать.

---

У меня есть класс например компьютер.

```
класс компьютер {

}
```

У класса есть объект в котором будет еще 2 поля

```
класс Компьютер {
    объект процессор {
        Строка производитель = "Intel";
        бул включен = да;
    }
}
```

И обращаться к объекту так

```
Компьютер асус = новый Компьютер();
Система.вывод.написать(асус.процессор.включен);
```

Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Скажи, пожалуйста, почему не подходит решение прошлого вопроса?

Comment: Ну и что я буду постоянно называть классы? а если таких 10 ? мне придется 10 раз писать одно и тоже?

Comment: Если это десять классов с совершенно разными полями, то да, придётся написать десять разных классов. Если поля похожи, то можно использовать наследование. Если поля совпадают, то можно написать **один** класс, затем десять раз создать экземпляры этого класса. (ну вроде бы)

Comment: Опиши поля этих десяти классов, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Computer {
    private Processor processor;
    /*another components*/

    public Computer(Processor processor) {
        this.processor = processor;
    }

    public Processor getProcessor() {
        return processor;
    }

    public void setProcessor(Processor processor) {
        this.processor = processor;
    }
}

class Processor {
    private final String fabricator;
    private boolean included;

    public Processor(String fabricator, boolean included) {
        this.fabricator = fabricator;
        this.included = included;
    }

    public String getFabricator() {
        return fabricator;
    }

    public boolean isIncluded() {
        return included;
    }

    public void setIncluded(boolean included) {
        this.included = included;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Computer asus = new Computer(new Processor("Intel", true));
        System.out.println(asus.getProcessor().isIncluded());
    }
}
```